# how to download multiple files to multiple folders in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm unable to download multiple files to multiple folder using selenium.
I used pref statements too but getting same error

When I run multiple files to a single folder. All the files are downloaded to the specific path but the problem comes when I download multiple files to multiple folders, in this care the files are downloaded to normal c drive instead of downloading to a specified path

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.